# How ticketing applications hold the seats when a transaction is fired and release them back to be made available again?

Tags: java, spring-boot, transactions, acid

Say a user selects a particular seat and opted out to book the ticket. In this case, how to hold the seat for a defined perdiod of time and release it back.

Answer (score 1):

You can hold the seat for some configured time (lets say 15mins). Lets say you have user A and B.
As soon as A books the seat, Your application can do the following

1. Set the initial time (Time at which seat was booked by A) in A's session.You can skip this step for distributed set up.
2. Set the initial time against the seat (lets say seatBookingTime ) in the database.

If user A performs any action during the lifecycle of the transaction, Your application will do the following:

1. Fetch initial time from A's session and check if the time has expired or not.For distributed set up, fetch initial time from the database only.

If user B tries to book the seat, Your application will do the following:

1. Get all those seats from the database for which 
   currentTime - seatBookingTime > 15mins

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was also looking into locking mechanisms of spring data jpa to solve the same. I'm new to jpa so if you have some insights about it, it'll be really appreciated.

Comment: I think JPA versioning should be enough. You dont really need lock.

Comment: so if versioning is carried out can we define the time of 15 mins to unlock in it?

Comment: @Sathish You can have a configurable variable lets say SetBookExpirationTime = 15mins in your application. Whenever user book a seat, just set current time against the booked seat and in user session (lets call it seatBookingTime). To display only available seats, you can use the following check: "Get all those seats from the database for which currentTime - seatBookingTime > SetBookExpirationTime". You dont really need lock for that.

Comment: thanks. Just out of curiosity does the real world applications like fandango etc works in a similar way?

Comment: @Sathish I have no idea about Fandango. Ideally all application prefer solutions that does not require lock. Locking impact performance for concurrent requests. Could you please upvote the answer if it helps you.